# Two Different Objects Created Using A Class Share The Same Memory

Tags: python, object, memory

I am working on a Python script, running a function that instantiates an object from a class. Running this function twice (supposedly creating two objects) creates two variables that point to the same memory location, effectively making me only one object. This would be understandable if the attributes of the object were the same both times, but they aren't. This means that the attributes of the first instantiation are overwritten by the second.

I've tried to make a deep copy to rectify this.

```
x = deepcopy(create_my_object(123))
y = deepcopy(create_my_object('abc'))
```

x and y still point to the same memory location. This means that the attribute '123' of object x is overwritten by 'abc'. I want two objects with each of those attributes.

Class:

```
class Sq:
    def __init__(self, source, queries):
        Sq.datetime_created = datetime.datetime.now()
        Sq.source = source
        Sq.queries = queries
        Sq.count = len(queries)
        Sq.filtered = False
```

So to summarise, calling this class with different sets of args doesn't create objects in different locations, I just end up with a single object with the attributes of the most recent instantiation.

Thanks in advance - myself and my peers are stumped!

Edit: The function to create the object looks like this:

```
def news(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.find_all(class_='top-story__title')
    return Sq(url, result)
```

Comment: 1) what does the create_my_object function look like ? may this content can help you : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I am aware of not copying things properly, but this isn't the case I think. I have added the function to the original post. Calling the function to create the class with different 'url' args doesn't create an object in a different area of memory, causing the old, different object to be overwritten :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Sq.__init__` method, you are setting the value of *class* variables, not instance variables. These values are shared by all instances of the class, and are overwritten in all instances when changed in any of them. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=static%20variables#class-and-instance-variables) for a description of class vs instance variables.

Change each line to, e.g., `self.datetime_created = datetime.datetime.now()`, etc.

Comment: I have not come across class vs instance variables but this is the answer. I love picking up new bits of Python knowledge! Thanks!